# Using a function in React defaultprops is returning an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Im having issues when reading defaultprops of where I use a translation function to read a value mapped to a labelkey. In this case it's a variable called 'greeting_component_title'.

```js
const GreetingComponent = ({ title, id, className }) => {

    console.log('id');

    return (
        <section id={id} className={className}>
            <p> {title} </p>
        </section>
    )
};

GreetingComponent.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
};

GreetingComponent.defaultProps = {
  title: translate('greeting_component_title'),
};

export default GreetingComponent;
```

Title in this case is an object of arrays when the translate function returns a string, however if i instead write default props like this

```js
GreetingComponent.defaultProps = {
  title: 'greeting_component_title',
};
```

and then use it in my `p` as such

`{translate(title)}`

it works perfectly. This was working a few months ago and I've just returned to it. I also tried using an arrow function in the defaultProps and it didn't work.

I cant find anything that tells me if something has changed regarding defaultprops not allowing for functions to run, am I missing something here?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with `translate` and `greeting_component_title`. Or maybe a timing problem. Can you add some information about these two?

Comment: Yeah. Translate is a simple selfmade function that I've imported, it takes one parameter in the form of a string, and then looks through a json file I have where I specify key-value pairs. If it finds one, it returns the value for that key, otherwise it returns the key itself.

greeting_component_title is just the key, i noticed i forgot to add quotes around it so I went ahead and did that. The translate function works in all other components, but this is the first time I've tried setting it in the default props.

Comment: Where does the json file come from? How does translate behave if the json file is not loaded when you call it? try using a getter.

Comment: The JSON file is in a folder located in the root folder of the project. Currently it has 15-20 key value pairs. If it finds a match, it returns the translation. However, if anything goes wrong currently it returns the initial key. it's a try catch where catch returns the key as well if it goes wrong.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for trying to help me, i actually finally found the issue being that since react 17, the syntax for defaultProps has been deprecated for functional components. I'll write it in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2396#issuecomment-539184761

Which confirmed my thoughts regarding defaultProps and it seems the syntax has changed. So instead of the code you see in my question, this was the answer

```js
const GreetingComponent = ({ 
    title = translate('greeting_component_title'),
    id,
    className
}) => {

    console.log('id');

    return (
        <section id={id} className={className}>
            <p> {title} </p>
        </section>
    )
};

GreetingComponent.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
};

export default GreetingComponent;
```